# Value within nested LOD - Max with in Max

Tags: sorting, filter, tableau-api

I have the following data.
One customer can have multiple account numbers. And one account number can have multiple transactions on a given day.

```
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| Customer ID | Account ID | Trx Date  | Trx Seq | Balance |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1           | A001       | 21-Jan-21 | 1       |      10 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1           | A001       | 21-Jan-21 | 2       |      20 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1           | A001       | 22-Jan-21 | 1       |      30 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1           | A001       | 30-Jan-21 | 1       |     -20 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1           | A001       | 30-Jan-21 | 2       |      10 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1           | A001       | 30-Jan-21 | 3       |     100 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1           | A002       | 15-Jan-21 | 3       |     110 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1           | A003       | 30-Jan-21 | 1       |     100 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 1           | A003       | 30-Jan-21 | 2       |         |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 2           | B001       | 10-Jan-21 | 1       |      50 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 2           | B001       | 30-Jan-21 | 1       |     -30 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 2           | B001       | 30-Jan-21 | 2       |    -100 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 2           | B001       |  1-Feb-21 | 3       |     100 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 2           | B001       |  1-Feb-21 | 4       |         |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 3           | C001       |  3-Feb-21 | 1       |      30 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
| 3           | C001       |  3-Feb-21 | 2       |      40 |
+-------------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Expected outcome is a customer level summary
For each customer, account number combination, find the last transaction date for each month.
If that transaction date has more than one transaction (determined by sequence number), then pick the last (max) sequence number and display the associated balance.

Outlier - There may be cases where there are no balances associated with a particular transaction/transaction date. In those cases, need to look at prior date details. This is a nice to have calculation, while I understand the source data may need to corrected for this issue.
[Sample Data Screengrab[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8USo.png)

Comment: Please update your question and add in your calculation / formula and explain what results it's giving you vs what results you expect.

Comment: Instead of giving the screenshot of input data, please save the sample file as CSV open it in some text editor, copy and paste the data in the question, please

Answer (score 0):

Use this calculated field say `last transaction` as a filter with TRUE values only,

```
{FIXED [Customer ID], [Account ID], DATETRUNC('month', [Trx Date]): 
max(
IF NOT ISNULL([Balance]) THEN [Trx Date] END
)} = [Trx Date]
and
{FIXED [Customer ID], [Account ID], DATETRUNC('month', [Trx Date]): 
max(
IF NOT ISNULL([Balance]) THEN [Trx Seq] END
)} = [Trx Seq]
```

See this screenshot, you can check

[image]

OR

filtered data (as desired)

[image]

Comment: Didn't it serve your purpose?